# Best Seller, Traducir o Eliminar opción de lista en Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

Tengo una situación con una lista desplegable dentro de mi Sitio-Plantilla de Prestashop 1.7.5.1, en la sección de productos aparece un Dropdown para filtrar por:

Best Seller, Relevancia, De A-Z, De Z-A, precio 0-1, precio 1-0

He buscado y buscado una forma de traducir la palabra Best Seller, porque mi sitio lo manejo solamente en español. Cuando una palabra no se traduce bien, desde el inspector de elementos busco el modulo que lo contiene y modifico el L S de este archivo al idioma que quiero, pero no encuentro Best Seller.

Dentro de esta ubicacion:  public_html/themes/MyPlantilla/templates/catalog/_partials/sort-orders.tpl

Encontré el archivo que es desde donde se toman las variables que se listan en ese Dropdown

```
 <div class="products-sort-order dropdown mb-1">
  <span class="sort-by">{l s='Sort by:' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</span>
  <div>
    <span data-toggle="dropdown">{if isset($listing.sort_selected)}{$listing.sort_selected}{else}{l 
    s='Select' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}{/if}<i class="linearicons-chevron-down ml-1"></i></span>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      {foreach from=$listing.sort_orders item=sort_order}
        <a
          rel="nofollow"
          href="{$sort_order.url}"
          class="select-list dropdown-item {['current' => $sort_order.current, 'js-search-link' => 
          true]|classnames}"
        >
          {$sort_order.label}
        </a>
      {/foreach}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No encuentro desde donde me llama la variable **$listing.sort_orders** que es donde creo que se encuentra la lista que se despliega en dicho dropdown.

He buscado por mas de 20 foros de Prestashop y no encuentro como solucionar esto. Hay una pregunta realizada desde el 2017 cuestionando esto igualmente y nadie ha respondido a este foro en Prestashop.

Alguien me puede decir como solucionarlo?

Comment: En la sección de Internacional>Traducciones en tipo de traducción pones **Traducciones de los módulos instalados**  y el módulo se llama **Búsqueda por facetas** y seleccionas el idioma en que lo quieres traducir de ahí das clic en modificar y buscas esa palabra ¿has probado ahí?

Comment: Hola @Ana Gracias por tu aporte, En busqueda por facetas no me aparece nada referente a Best Seller, eso tambien lo he comprobado en el archivo /public_html/modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Ps_FacetedsearchProductSearchProvider.php en donde se ve que la funcion nunca lista Best Seller pero si lista Relevancia, De A-Z, De Z-A, precio 0-1, precio 1-0. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Pienso que tal vez está en unos de los archivos de traducción , te recomiendo que descargues textpad es un editor de texto pero tiene una opción que te permite buscar palabras en una ruta determinada y lo apuntaras hacia tu carpeta de translations, hay una en la raíz de de tus archivos y otra dentro de tu tema, cuando lo descargues pones la palabra que quieres encontrar, en tipo de archivo pones que todos o sea un .* Y pruebas con la ruta de ambas carpetas de translations a ver si encuentra esa palabra en alguna de ellas

Comment: Si la encuentras deberás modificar la traducción en la etiqueta que dice <target>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

respondo a mi pregunta después de investigaciones, al parecer es algo bien común en plantillas de PrestaShop tener problemas a la hora de hacer esta traducción.

La traducción de 'Best sellers' debería modificarse en ***Internacional->Traducciones->Traducciones de módulos->Búsqueda por facetas->Tienda*** Pero no aparece allí debido a un bug de PrestaShop 1751. [IMAGEN1](https://prnt.sc/xpsc3a)

Puedes intentar otras recomendaciones de traducción en el foro de PrestaShop [FORUM #1](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/958547-prestashop-1751-translations-not-saving-updating/?tab=comments#comment-3216893)

Si ninguna de estas opciones te funciona puedes ir al código directamente y modificar archivo .php directamente ubicado ***modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Product/SearchProvider.php*** [IMAGEN2](https://prnt.sc/xps7qc)

Espero que a alguien le ayude esto.